# Interior angle of a polyhedral cone

Tags: angle, polyhedra, convex-cone, solid-angle

What is the angle subtended by a polyhedral cone $\{\pmb{\theta}\in\mathbb{R}^{m}:A\pmb{\theta}\ge\pmb{0}\}$ at its vertex (the origin) where $A$ is a full-rank matrix ? Also what is the solid angle around the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ ?

Comment: Are you asking for an explicit formula, or an algorithm, or something else? Also can you explain a bit more what the "subtended angle" should be?

Comment: How do we extend the "subtended angle" concept in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to higher dimensions ? I'm looking for a formula or an algorithm for the subtended angle.

Comment: I think the solid angle is the standard generalization of the "angle at the apex", but don't you have a specific application in mind and should therefore know what definition of angle you need?

Comment: Yes, I need to calculate the interior angle of a polyhedral cone with vertex at the origin in higher dimensions. It is obvious in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. The cone is the space enclosed within rays emanating from the origin.